# Pasar valor de una variable de un controller laravel a una variable de javascript

Tags: laravel

en el controlador tengo la siguiente variable:

```
$categories_1 = Category::orderBy('name','ASC')->whereIn('name', ['Tramite Juridico','Tramite-Division','Tramite-Unificacion','Croquis','Estado Tecnico','Tasacion'])->get()->pluck('name', 'id');
```

de la tabla category solo extraigo los registros que deseo. con eso no hay problema, el caso es que en la vista en un script deseo recuperar esa variable lo cual hago de esta forma:

`<script>
var categoria_1= '{{$categories_1}}';
console.log(categoria_1)
</script>`

al aplicar alert(categoria_1); lo que me trae es lo siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

si alguien tiene alguna idea porfa se lo  agradesco desde ya...

Comment: prueba con `var categoria_1= '{!!$categories_1!!}';`

Comment: Gracias hermano, de esa forma si lo trae correctamente, dale un abrazo

Comment: genia! hice una respuesta con una pequeña argumentación para que se entienda un poco mejor

Answer (score 2):

Usa `{!! !!}` -> `var categoria_1= '{!!$categories_1!!}';`

Si pasas una variable desde un controlador a una vista, por ejemplo con un estilo HTML:

```
$nombre = "<b> William </b>";
```

Y accedes a ella en Blade, con `{{ $nombre }}`, en el navegador verás:

```
<b> William </b>
```

Pero si se accedes con `{!! $nombre !!}` entonces verás:

**William**

Explicado en la [Documentación](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/blade#displaying-data) (una traducción aproximada):

## Visualización de datos no escapados

De forma predeterminada, las declaraciones de Blade `{{}}` se envían automáticamente a través de la función `htmlentities` de PHP para evitar ataques XSS. Si no desea que se escapen sus datos, puede utilizar la siguiente sintaxis:

```
Hola, {!! $nombre !!}.
```

**Nota**: tenga mucho cuidado al hacer echo del contenido que proporcionan los usuarios de su aplicación. Siempre use la sintaxis de llaves dobles para escapar de cualquier entidad HTML en el contenido.